# Exponential series problem

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, algebraic-geometry

If $$a = 1 + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^6}{6!} + ...\infty$$
$$b = x + \frac{x^4}{4!} + \frac{x^7}{7!} + ...\infty$$
$$c = \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} + \frac{x^8}{8!} + ...\infty$$
show that $$a^3 + b^3 + c^3 -3abc = 1$$

I understand $$a^3 + b^3 + c^3 -3abc = (a + b + c) (a^2 + b^2 + c^2 -ab- bc -ca)$$
and $$(a+b+c) = e^x$$ It means somehow I have to derive other factor to be $e^-x$ and there is where my difficult lies. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you know how to formally multiply two power series' together?

Comment: Should the $x^2$ term in the expression of $c$ be $\frac{x^2}{2!}$?

Answer (score 5):

$$a+b+c=\exp(x)$$
$$a+\omega b+\omega^2 c=\exp(\omega x)$$
$$a+\omega^2 b+\omega c=\exp(\omega^2 x)$$
where $\omega=\exp(2\pi i/3)$.
Thus
$$(a+b+c)(a+\omega b+\omega^2 c)(a+\omega^2 b+\omega c)=\exp((1
+\omega+\omega^2)x).$$
This simplifies to
$$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=1.$$

Comment: yes... perfectly done. Thank you.